# BibTex Numbering in Reference List (.bst file custom)

Tags: bibtex

I am using MikTex.

I am trying to apply the Biblio style "abbvr" to my document (which is not the article class, but another customer class)

What I am interested in is having references numbered in the text as [1].
As well as numbered and arrange alphabetically in the Reference list
[1] ...
[2] ...

Abbvr is supposed to do this automatically as far as I understand but it does not... There is no number in bracket that appears. I have tried several commun styles that should give this render but none work. I am wondering if mis-compatibilities may occur with the .cls file.

Or How to create my own .bst file?

Os is biblatex something I should be downloading to do more?

Comment: Usually, there should be a number when you use `\cite` after you have run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Do you get a question mark or no output at all between the square brackets? Is this about the citation or about the bibliography? If none of the styles you tried work, then it seems plausible that the problem might be in your `.cls` or with the packages you load. Please show us a short example document that reproduces the issue. If you use a `.cls` that is not available on CTAN, please share a link to where we can obtain it.

Comment: Within the text when doing \cite I get indeed a number in brackets, (1) that is working fine
In the reference list I do no get anything. No brackets, no number, just directly the name of the author.
For example loading vancouver.bst does not produce these brackets. 
I would need to create a small case as you suggested to show you.

On CTAN you can find the mnras.cls   The .bst referencing it uses is the one i am trying to transform into having [1] in front of authors name in the Reference List

Comment: This suggests that your `.cls` file (or some other package you load, or some code in your preamble) redefines the bibliography environment to drop the numbers. I don't want to speculate, so I'd need to see some code to be able to help. Best would be a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Make sure that the MWE can be compiled with only the info in the question in a new, empty folder. If you need external files that are not on CTAN, provide them in the question or link to where we can find them.

Comment: Can you access the mnras.cls from the CTAN website? It is included within TEXLIVE and MikTex.  The biography style I am trying to use is the open source vancouver.bst

Comment: % safe_template.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{safe}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\title[Short]{Title}
\author[J. Smith et al.]{
John. Smith,$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: \href{mailto:JSmith@Test.com}{JSmith@Test1.com}} 
A. N. Other,$^{1,2}$
\\
$^{1}$Test\\
$^{2}$Test1
}
\date{Sept 5}
\pubyear{2019}
\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle
Test \cite{APA}, \cite{article}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bsp
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
% End

Comment: Sorry this is my first time here, I fail to understand how to write code and make it look like code... Or how to provide you with the files you need? How do people normally do this? I read about the MWE, but I still don't understand what to do. Sorry :(